# Making an applications stay on the phone "permanently"

Tags: rooting, system-apps

I would like to be able to make an Android application remain on the phone even after a factory reset and/or a system upgrade.

Some people suggested that the way to accomplish this is to root the phone put the desired application in the system/app and unroot the phone.

What I was wondering is - is there a less aggressive way (avoiding rooting the phone) to accomplish this? What would be the standard way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is the reason of "avoiding rooting the phone" linked to warranty of your device? If that's the case then I'm afraid that you don't possibly have a choice.

Comment: @Firelord No not related to warranty, I just thought this was not a clean way to do it and was wondering if there is a more standard way.

Comment: If you really don't want to root, edit your rom files and flash them:)

Comment: Why don't you just keep the `apk` of the program somewhere on your filesystem that doesn't get erased w/factory restore? Or, with the ubiquity of cloud storage services, just keep it on Google Drive, dropbox, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no.

If you want to completely copy app from phone to another storage you need usually root. And for making app as a system app, you need unfortunately root as well.